# Using a conditional to display either column value or concatenated text, AND exclude from GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently working on a personal project where I take the Lehman Access Baseball Database, convert it to MSSQL and build out functionality against it.  I've managed to convert the database and I've built out three statstical views for Batting, Pitching and Fielding.

I am currently working on a query against the batting view to return a list of players that qualified for the batting title.  This is how far I've gotten:

```
SELECT Player, Season, SUM(AB) AS AB, SUM(BB)AS BB, SUM(HBP) AS HBP,
SUM(SH)AS SH, SUM(SF) AS SF, AVG(AVG)AS AVG, AVG(OBP) AS OBP, 
AVG(SLG) AS SLG, AVG(OPS) AS OPS 
FROM View_PlayerBatting 
WHERE Season = '2016' 
GROUP BY Player, Season 
HAVING (SUM(AB) + SUM(BB) + SUM(HBP) + SUM(SH) + SUM(SF)) > 502 
ORDER BY AVG(OPS) DESC
```

I am using the Order By clause to check my results against a verified master (MLB.com).

The problem I have is that I also wish to include Teams on this list, and some of the players were traded mid-season, so to figure out qualifiers I don't want to group by team (grouping by team removes seven otherwise qualified results).  However, if I try to add to the SELECT clause, something like:

```
IIF(COUNT(Team) = 1, Team, CAST(COUNT(Team) AS varchar) + ' teams') AS Team
```

to my select clause, it forces me to include team in GROUP BY.  It also forces me to include team by GROUP BY if I try to use a subquery to return the value from another table, such as:

```
IIF(COUNT(Team) = 1, (SELECT teamID FROM Teams where TeamID = View_PlayerBatting.Team), ...
```

It seems like if I *need* to know the value of Team, I have to include it in the GROUP BY clause; if I change the first result of the IIF to return something other than the Team column, like a static value or character string, the query will execute without requiring Team being in the GROUP BY.  How do return the Team column in the format I'm trying to present it in?

Comment: Perhaps you can simplify the data and show sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with that database, but you are basically looking to solve the **top 1 per group** problem. You could use `max(Team)` but that might not get you the team you want.

You can use `cross apply()` to get 1 team per player and season ordered by some column like `TradeDate` like so:

```
SELECT Player, Season, x.Team
, SUM(AB) AS AB, SUM(BB)AS BB, SUM(HBP) AS HBP,
SUM(SH)AS SH, SUM(SF) AS SF, AVG(AVG)AS AVG, AVG(OBP) AS OBP, 
AVG(SLG) AS SLG, AVG(OPS) AS OPS 
FROM View_PlayerBatting 
cross apply (
  select top 1
    Team
  from View_PlayerBatting as i 
  where i.Player = View_PlayerBatting.Player
    and i.Season = View_PlayerBatting.Season
  order by TradeDate desc
  ) as x
WHERE Season = '2016' 
GROUP BY Player, Season, x.Team
HAVING (SUM(AB) + SUM(BB) + SUM(HBP) + SUM(SH) + SUM(SF)) > 502 
ORDER BY AVG(OPS) DESC
```

If you want to get all the `team` values for each player concatenated, you could use the [**`stuff()`** with **`select ... for xml path ('')`** method of string concatenation](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/).

```
SELECT Player, Season,
 , Team = stuff((
      select distinct '; '+i.Team
      from View_PlayerBatting as i 
      where i.Player = View_PlayerBatting.Player
        and i.Season = View_PlayerBatting.Season
      for xml path (''), type).value('.','varchar(max)')
    ,1,2,'')
  , SUM(AB) AS AB, SUM(BB)AS BB, SUM(HBP) AS HBP
  , SUM(SH)AS SH, SUM(SF) AS SF, AVG(AVG)AS AVG, AVG(OBP) AS OBP
  , AVG(SLG) AS SLG, AVG(OPS) AS OPS 
FROM View_PlayerBatting 
WHERE Season = '2016' 
GROUP BY Player, Season, x.Team
HAVING (SUM(AB) + SUM(BB) + SUM(HBP) + SUM(SH) + SUM(SF)) > 502 
ORDER BY AVG(OPS) DESC;
```

Comment: Actually, using MAX solves the problem, I didn't think about it.  "IIF(COUNT(Team) = 1, MAX(Team), CAST(COUNT(Team) AS Varchar) + ' teams') AS Team" returns the team if there is one team, or 'X teams' if there is more than one.

Comment: @K_Cruz Great! Glad you found a satisfactory solution. I have updated my answer to include concatenated `team` as another alternative.